# Query on combination of multiple tables (New)

Tags: sql-server

I have a question on the same topic, but it is on hold.  I do not know how to close that post.  So I post it here again because I have a solution on that question.

My New question is that are there other ways to reproduce my query.

---

This is from the original question:

This is a table combination question. We have 2-N source tables. Each table has a processor id, an event name, and an event time. We need to combine all source table into one target table.

### The combination rule is: any event in one source table must be combined with the most recent (relative to that table) event in all other source tables. If an event in one source table does not have any most recent event in one of other source tables, NULL will be added to the target table.

My solution (an example of three source tables. It is like hard coded, so I am trying to get a more simpler way to code this, for the case when I have 20 source tables):

```
create table #Ev1 (Pid INT, Ev1Name VARCHAR(20), Ev1Time DateTime)
INSERT INTO #Ev1 VALUES
     (1,   'ev11', '2015-06-01 02:00:00')
    ,(1,   'ev12', '2015-06-02 10:00:00')
    ,(1,   'ev13', '2015-06-03 18:00:00')


create table #Ev2 (Pid INT, Ev2Name VARCHAR(20), Ev2Time DateTime)
INSERT INTO #Ev2 VALUES 
     (1,   'ev21', '2015-06-01 6:20:00')
    ,(1,   'ev22', '2015-06-01 10:33:00') 
    ,(1,   'ev23', '2015-06-01 14:58:00')

create table #Ev3 (Pid INT, Ev3Name VARCHAR(20), Ev3Time DateTime)
INSERT INTO #Ev3 VALUES 
     (1,   'ev31', '2015-06-01 3:07:00')
    ,(1,   'ev32', '2015-06-01 4:12:00')
    ,(1,   'ev33', '2015-06-01 14:41:00')
```

---

```
 Select 
   Ev1.Pid
  ,Ev1.Ev1Name
  ,Ev1.Ev1Time
  ,(select top 1 Ev21.Ev2Name from #Ev2 Ev21
    where Ev21.Ev2Time <= Ev1.Ev1Time ORDER BY Ev21.Ev2Time DESC) As Ev2Name
  ,(select top 1 Ev21.Ev2Time from #Ev2 Ev21
    where Ev21.Ev2Time <= Ev1.Ev1Time ORDER BY Ev21.Ev2Time DESC) As Ev2Time  
  ,(select top 1 Ev31.Ev3Name from #Ev3 Ev31
    where Ev31.Ev3Time <= Ev1.Ev1Time ORDER BY Ev31.Ev3Time DESC) As Ev3Name
  ,(select top 1 Ev31.Ev3Time from #Ev3 Ev31
    where Ev31.Ev3Time <= Ev1.Ev1Time ORDER BY Ev31.Ev3Time DESC) As Ev3Time   
 INTO #FINAL                                          
 FROM #Ev1 Ev1
 INNER JOIN #Ev2 Ev2
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev2.Pid
  INNER JOIN #Ev3 Ev3
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev3.Pid
 )
 INSERT INTO #FINAL 
Select 
   Ev2.Pid
  ,(select top 1 Ev11.Ev1Name from #Ev1 Ev11
    where Ev11.Ev1Time <= Ev2.Ev2Time ORDER BY Ev11.Ev1Time DESC) As Ev1Name
  ,(select top 1 Ev11.Ev1Time from #Ev1 Ev11
    where Ev11.Ev1Time <= Ev2.Ev2Time ORDER BY Ev11.Ev1Time DESC) As Ev1Time
  ,Ev2.Ev2Name
  ,Ev2.Ev2Time 
  ,(select top 1 Ev31.Ev3Name from #Ev3 Ev31
    where Ev31.Ev3Time <= Ev2.Ev2Time ORDER BY Ev31.Ev3Time DESC) As Ev3Name
  ,(select top 1 Ev31.Ev3Time from #Ev3 Ev31
    where Ev31.Ev3Time <= Ev2.Ev2Time ORDER BY Ev31.Ev3Time DESC) As Ev3Time  

 FROM #Ev1 Ev1
 INNER JOIN #Ev2 Ev2
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev2.Pid
 INNER JOIN #Ev3 Ev3
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev3.Pid
```

---

```
 INSERT INTO #FINAL 
Select 
   Ev3.Pid
  ,(select top 1 Ev11.Ev1Name from #Ev1 Ev11
    where Ev11.Ev1Time <= Ev3.Ev3Time ORDER BY Ev11.Ev1Time DESC) As Ev1Name
  ,(select top 1 Ev11.Ev1Time from #Ev1 Ev11
    where Ev11.Ev1Time <= Ev3.Ev3Time ORDER BY Ev11.Ev1Time DESC) As Ev1Time
  ,(select top 1 Ev21.Ev2Name from #Ev2 Ev21
    where Ev21.Ev2Time <= Ev3.Ev3Time ORDER BY Ev21.Ev2Time DESC) As Ev2Name
  ,(select top 1 Ev21.Ev2Time from #Ev2 Ev21
    where Ev21.Ev2Time <= Ev3.Ev3Time ORDER BY Ev21.Ev2Time DESC) As Ev2Time    
  ,Ev3.Ev3Name
  ,Ev3.Ev3Time 

 FROM #Ev1 Ev1
 INNER JOIN #Ev2 Ev2
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev2.Pid
 INNER JOIN #Ev3 Ev3
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev3.Pid


SELECT distinct * FROM #FINAL 
ORDER BY Pid,Ev1Time, Ev2Time, Ev3Time  


--select * from #Ev1    
--select * from #Ev2
--select * from #Ev3
drop table #Ev1
drop table #Ev2
drop table #Ev3
drop table #FINAL
```

---

The results:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Pid ║ Ev1Name ║         Ev1Time         ║ Ev2Name ║         Ev2Time         ║ Ev3Name ║         Ev3Time         ║
╠═════╬═════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║   1 ║ ev11    ║ 2015-06-01 02:00:00.000 ║ NULL    ║ NULL                    ║ NULL    ║ NULL                    ║
║   1 ║ ev11    ║ 2015-06-01 02:00:00.000 ║ NULL    ║ NULL                    ║ ev31    ║ 2015-06-01 03:07:00.000 ║
║   1 ║ ev11    ║ 2015-06-01 02:00:00.000 ║ NULL    ║ NULL                    ║ ev32    ║ 2015-06-01 04:12:00.000 ║
║   1 ║ ev11    ║ 2015-06-01 02:00:00.000 ║ ev21    ║ 2015-06-01 06:20:00.000 ║ ev32    ║ 2015-06-01 04:12:00.000 ║
║   1 ║ ev11    ║ 2015-06-01 02:00:00.000 ║ ev22    ║ 2015-06-01 10:33:00.000 ║ ev32    ║ 2015-06-01 04:12:00.000 ║
║   1 ║ ev11    ║ 2015-06-01 02:00:00.000 ║ ev22    ║ 2015-06-01 10:33:00.000 ║ ev33    ║ 2015-06-01 14:41:00.000 ║
║   1 ║ ev11    ║ 2015-06-01 02:00:00.000 ║ ev23    ║ 2015-06-01 14:58:00.000 ║ ev33    ║ 2015-06-01 14:41:00.000 ║
║   1 ║ ev12    ║ 2015-06-02 10:00:00.000 ║ ev23    ║ 2015-06-01 14:58:00.000 ║ ev33    ║ 2015-06-01 14:41:00.000 ║
║   1 ║ ev13    ║ 2015-06-03 18:00:00.000 ║ ev23    ║ 2015-06-01 14:58:00.000 ║ ev33    ║ 2015-06-01 14:41:00.000 ║
╚═════╩═════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you Ali for the reformatting!

Comment: Why the question?   There is usually more than one way to do something in SQL.   But are you asking for some specific reason?

Comment: Yes Tab.  Sometimes we have a lot of source tables (20) to combine.  As you see in my query (3 source tables) the combination is too complicate to do acombination for 20 tables.  So I try to find a way to write the sql in a simpler way.  My query looks as if it is hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

THe following query give the same result, except without the rows with NULLs.  If we add a default row to the beginning of each source table, this query can generate the rows for NULLs.

--added row:  (1,   'ev00', '1915-01-01 00:00:00')

```
Select 
  Ev1.Pid
 ,Ev1Name
 ,Ev1Time
 ,Ev2Name
 ,Ev2Time  
 ,Ev3Name
 ,Ev3Time      
INTO #FINAL                                      
FROM #Ev1 Ev1
INNER JOIN #Ev2 Ev2
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev2.Pid
AND Ev2Time = (SELECT MAX(Ev2Time) FROM #Ev2 Ev21 WHERE Ev21.Ev2Time <= Ev1.Ev1Time)
INNER JOIN #Ev3 Ev3
 ON Ev1.Pid = Ev3.Pid
AND Ev3Time = (SELECT MAX(Ev3Time) FROM #Ev3 Ev31 WHERE Ev31.Ev3Time <= Ev1.Ev1Time)


insert INTO #FINAL 
  Select 
    Ev2.Pid
   ,Ev1Name
   ,Ev1Time
   ,Ev2Name
   ,Ev2Time  
   ,Ev3Name
   ,Ev3Time                                            
  FROM #Ev1 Ev1
  INNER JOIN #Ev2 Ev2
    ON Ev1.Pid = Ev2.Pid
   AND Ev1Time = (SELECT MAX(Ev1Time) FROM #Ev1 Ev11 WHERE Ev11.Ev1Time <= Ev2.Ev2Time)
  INNER JOIN #Ev3 Ev3
    ON Ev1.Pid = Ev3.Pid
   AND Ev3Time = (SELECT MAX(Ev3Time) FROM #Ev3 Ev31 WHERE Ev31.Ev3Time <= Ev2.Ev2Time)

 insert INTO #FINAL 
   Select 
     Ev3.Pid
    ,Ev1Name
    ,Ev1Time
    ,Ev2Name
    ,Ev2Time  
    ,Ev3Name
    ,Ev3Time                                            
   FROM #Ev3 Ev3
   INNER JOIN #Ev1 Ev1
     ON Ev1.Pid = Ev3.Pid
    AND Ev1Time = (SELECT MAX(Ev1Time) FROM #Ev1 Ev11 WHERE Ev11.Ev1Time <= Ev3.Ev3Time)
   INNER JOIN #Ev2 Ev2
     ON Ev1.Pid = Ev2.Pid
   AND Ev2Time = (SELECT MAX(Ev2Time) FROM #Ev2 Ev21 WHERE Ev21.Ev2Time <= Ev3.Ev3Time)

select distinct * from #final    

drop table #Ev1
drop table #Ev2
drop table #Ev3
drop table #final
```